# Why isn't my if-else block ever getting hit, even though it should be? (Just need another pair of eyes.)

Tags: java, if-statement, simulation

I am making a Falling Sand style game in Java, and I'm having weird issues with an if-else block that I have. In my doGravity() method, I have an various blocks of conditions that will cause different things to happen, and for some odd reason, one block is NEVER getting hit.

When I have this block count how many times each condition is hit, the left and right blocks are hit almost evenly:

```
else if(world[x][y+1]==EMPTY && (x-1 >= 0) && world[x-1][y+1] == EMPTY && (x+1 < world.length) && world[x+1][y+1]==EMPTY) {
    int r = rand.nextInt(50);
    if(r == 0) {
        world[x-1][y+1] = world[x][y];
        //System.out.println("GO: right");
        countRight++;
    }
    else if(r == 1) {
        world[x+1][y+1] = world[x][y];
        //System.out.println("GO: left");
        countLeft++;
    }
    else {
        world[x][y+1] = world[x][y];
        countCenter++;
    }
    world[x][y] = EMPTY;
}
```

Next comes this condition, which also equally distributes left and right.

```
else if((x-1 >= 0) && world[x-1][y+1] == EMPTY && (x+1 < world.length) && world[x+1][y+1]==EMPTY) {
    if(rand.nextBoolean()) {
        world[x-1][y+1] = world[x][y];
        //countLeft++;
    }
    else {
        world[x+1][y+1] = world[x][y];
        //countRight++;
    }
    world[x][y] = EMPTY;
}
```

But when I count these blocks, the left block NEVER gets hit, even when the space to the left *is open*. I feel like its probably just some stupid typo that I can't see for some reason.

```
else if((x-1 >= 0) && world[x-1][y+1] == EMPTY) {
    world[x-1][y+1] = world[x][y];
    world[x][y] = EMPTY;
    countLeft++;
    System.out.println("Hit Left");
}
else if((x+1 < world.length) && world[x+1][y+1] == EMPTY) {
    world[x+1][y+1] = world[x][y];
    world[x][y] = EMPTY;
    countRight++;
    System.out.println("Hit Right");
}
```

**UPDATE:** If I remark out the `left` block at the end, absolutely nothing changes. The sand acts exactly the same. If I remark out the `right` block at the end, it acts the same as if I remark out both blocks. I cannot figure this out. It should work... but it doesn't.

**UPDATE:** Here's the full source code. I have no idea what this could possibly be. It will, in fact, drive me insane. http://pastebin.com/mXCbCvmb

Comment: Do you get the correct effects from the countRight++ block? In particular, does x have sensible values? An accidental assignment of 0 to x could be a cause.

Comment: Yep, everything is working correctly in that aspect. If I run the applet, you can even see the sand hit the floor, start building a pile, then flow to the right while the left side is a straight line. Then, when I remark out the last two `else if` blocks, the sand builds a tower straight up in the air.

Comment: Ok, my last guess would be to try and remove the else before the left-checking if (first line of last snippet) , just in case you have some if/else nesting issues.

Comment: Just tried that, nope its not that. I added an update with some more experimentation. This is a real puzzle.

Comment: What happens if you comment out either of the conditions x-1>=0 and world[...=EMPTY, which one is misbehaving?

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. I put the source in a Pastebin. http://pastebin.com/mXCbCvmb It probably won't help though, I'm sure the error is in this block.

Comment: A good IDE like Intellij IDEA will highlight if/elseif/else blocks and tell you when code is un-reachable because the first criteria will always be met.

Comment: That's not the problem. The block that is *always* being reached is after the block that is *never* being reached, when it absolutely should be reached at least *sometimes.*

Comment: From printlining, it looks like the left block's conditions are consumed entirely by the first and third else-if blocks, 99% of the time by the first.

Comment: I was thinking of that, and I'm not exactly sure how to fix that. In theory, the right block shouldn't ever be reached either, since all the previous conditions should also kill it.

Comment: (x - 1 >= 0) && world[x - 1][y + 1] == EMPTY && !(world[x][y + 1] == EMPTY || (world[x + 1][y + 1] == EMPTY && (x + 1 < world.length)))

If this expression resolves as true, the left block should trigger. Question is, why doesn't it ever resolve as true?

Comment: So basically, it never seems to transpire that the left way is clear when the centre and right ways are not. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Scratch all that, it does transpire. It just seems to take several seconds before suddenly transpiring an awful lot. Why is that? And why do I keep ending my comments with questions?

Comment: Well, it would appear that Captain Giraffe has solved the problem. The left side was never being properly hit and the particles were heading to the right because the algorithm for gravity tracking was going from left-to-right, top to bottom. Captain Giraffe randomized it, and now all is well. Four hours of looking at the wrong code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pastebin code does show "Hit left", you just need to change the creation of world (line 65 pastebin) to

```
    world = new Color[worldWidth][worldHeight+1];
```

Because of the y+1 part i would suppose. Other than that it grows both to the left and to the right.

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/GVmSzN4z  I twiddled a little with your doGravity to make the drops a little more symmetric.

Comment: So it turns out that the left side was never hit because of the way that the gravity processing algorithm works. dropParticle() was never the issue, it's just the fact that doGravity() went from left-to-right and bottom to top. Now, your revised doGravity() is horrendously slow considering all that has to happen in the rest of the script, but it's the right idea. Problem solved!

Comment: @Nick, shuffle is actually quite fast, just move the creation of jS = new ArrayList.  to init and you'll be fine.  Also Jarrods comments are very useful when its as compound as this.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. I just noticed a massive performance drop once I implemented your version, but it's probably just because of the variable creation inside the method. I'm trying to keep everything down to primitives to make it run faster, so repeated creation is killing it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see anything strange in the posted code... however the "else" at the beginning of the second block makes me think that probably the above condition is being executed in cases that insted you would like to be handled by the "left" case.
What is the condition in the `if` before that part?

### EDIT

After checking your full source code I finally found where the problem is. Your `doGravity` update function always goes left->right and this introduces the asymmetry. By changing it so that the update direction is alternating between left->right and right->left for odd/even scanlines the asymmetry disappears.

```
private void doGravity() {
    for(int i = worldHeight - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < worldWidth; j++) {
                if(world[j][i] != EMPTY) {
                    if(hasGravity(world[j][i])) {
                        dropParticle(j, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            for(int j = worldWidth-1; j >= 0; --j) {
                if(world[j][i] != EMPTY) {
                    if(hasGravity(world[j][i])) {
                        dropParticle(j, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited it to include the block in between. This block is also equally distributed. The left-only block just never gets hit. Ever.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either... what's the `if` condition at the top? All this code is only executed if that condition is false...

Comment: Well, all this code is definitely being executed. The `if` statement is `if(y == worldHeight-1)`. This only executes if the particle is at the very bottom of the frame, which either a.) deletes it if the floor is turned off, or b.) does nothing if the floor is turned on. I can run the code and the counters work properly in each block (I only have the counters in one section at a time), except the last section. Left is never executed.

Comment: Your problem then is somewhere else. This code does indeed increment both left and right counters (I copied and pasted from your question, wrote everything else needed to make it a full running program and tested it).

Comment: Here's the code. http://pastebin.com/mXCbCvmb I'm sure this method is causing the issues, however.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code from paste bin the first thing I did was extract this method and use it instead of all the embedded array cell checking so I could set a break point and see what the values for `x` and `y` and what the contents of that indexed cell was.

```
private boolean isEmpty(final int x, final int y)
{
    return world[x][y] == EMPTY;
}
```

I would extract all the `EMPTY` checks to something more readable, such as `isLeftEmpty(x,y)` and `isRightEmpty(x,y)` and `isNextLeftEmpty(x,y)` it will help you reason about the correctness of your logic in your code.

I would also extract the `(x + 1 < world.length)` to `isNextXOutsideWorld(x)`, this will help document your intentions and help with reasoning about the logic you intend as well.

This also has a side effect of simplifying the logic in the `if/elseif/else` statements.

I did some brief debugging and I let it run for a few minutes and came to the conclusion that the following line matches always and supersedes the next `else if` statement.

```
else if ((x + 1 < world.length) && isEmpty(x + 1, y + 1) && 
         (x - 1 >= 0) && isEmpty(x - 1,y + 1))
```

is always true when I run it, so it never reaches the next statement

```
else if ((x - 1 >= 0) && isEmpty(x - 1,y + 1))
```

I would try and break each of the `else/if` statements out to method calls with descriptive names and just all them all in order using a `Strategy` pattern since they are all mutually exclusive. That large of a method is definitely a code smell, compounded with all those `else/if` blocks, the stinky factor is high.

It is very hard to extrapolate what your intended behavior is from all the noise in the `if/elseif/else` blocks.